# Excel time duration: from total amout of minutes to hh:mm

Tags: excel, time, duration

I'm stuck with the time functions in Excel.
I have a table filled with a number of minutes. I can easly count the number of hours by dividing the number of minutes by 60. But this gives me a real number which I can't find how to translate into a duration. I find it easier to read 37h 36min than 37.6 hours.

```
                what I have              what I want
            minutes    hours
monday      2160       36                  36:00
tuesday     2255       37.6                37:36
wednesday   1715       28.6                28:36
```

Note that when I apply the [h]:mm@ format to the cells it does not work. I guess because my initial data is in real value and not in time format...

Comment: Your math is wrong.  `2255/60 => 37.583333` which would => `37:35`  not `37:36`, unless you also want to `ROUND` to the nearest 10th of an hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel stores time as fractions of a day.

There are 1440 minutes in a day (60*24)

So:

```
=TEXT(A2/1440,"[hh]:mm")
```

[image]

If you just want to format the cell, so as to have a numeric value rather than a text string,  then use:

```
=A2/1440
```

and format that cell as `[hh]:mm`

Answer (score 0):

Super late to the party but the TIME() function can be used

=TIME(FLOOR(A2/60,1),MOD(A2,60),0)

or

=TIME(ROUNDDOWN(A2/60,0),MOD(A2,60),0)